# General solution to a second order DE

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I am given the differential equation $2x''+4x'+8x=2e^{\alpha t}$, where I need to solve the equation for $\alpha = -1, 0$. On the surface this is the same as solving for $y$ but the variable is changed to $x$. So, the process should go like this: I should find $x=x_h+x_p$, the rest of the process should go the way you solve a normal second order differential equation right? I calculated $x=e^{-t}(c_1\cos(\sqrt3t))+c_2\sin(\sqrt t)+ \frac{1}{4}$ for the value $\alpha = 0$. Is this correct? What about when $\alpha = -1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's correct for $\alpha=0$:
$$x(t)=e^{-t}(C_1\cos(\sqrt 3t)+C_2\sin(\sqrt3 t))+ \frac{1}{4}$$
For $\alpha=-1$
Try:
$$x_p=Ae^{-t}$$

---

The DE is equivalent to:
$$2x''+4x'+8x=2e^{- t}$$
$$(xe^t)''+3xe^t=1$$
$$y''+3y=1$$
Where $y=xe^t$.